# How to synthetize custom uid in Plone / LDAP

Tags: ldap, plone

I'd like to use LDAP authentication (precisely Active Directory) in Plone (v4), however, the `uid` would not be simply one of LDAP user attributes, but i have to generate it myself (construct it from various LDAP user attributes, normalize the case, ..)

What Plone component (file) do you recommend me to modify? Or, is it even possible to solve it implanting a custom function in ZMI somewhere?

(I'm using PloneLDAP / plone.app.ldap)

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously reconsider your use-case. The uid in Plone is not really shown in user-facing pages, so it is not an issue if it is not pretty. If you're using ActiveDirectory, sticking with sAMAccountName will save you endless troubles in future upgrades.

Then, you can make all kinds of modifications to get nice looking Usernames or whatever, but your basic auth will be future-proof.

Constructing your own uid is a recipe for disaster, there ***will*** be an edge-case you didn't foresee, where you will end up with non-unique uids, weird issues with charsets, or other preventable headaches.

Comment: well, i'm going to do this to prevent some problems .. i know what is the current state of data in out particular active directory, and what i want and need to do :)

Comment: Still, you will lose all benefit of having an LDAP in the first place, and also prevent future integration of LDAP-dependant services within Plone. Something like the xmpp-collaboration.

it seems much more logical to fix your AD, even (if nothing else helps) by defining a new attribute on there to your specifications, filling that with a little script, and then using that as the UID.